# Does offscreen canvas take up drawing power?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

When we draw on off screen canvas are we actually taking up any drawing power(as in is it really drawing some thing? or just data?) or space? and what happens to the other part of the sprite sheet when we only draw on part of it, does it take up any memory space? same applies to clipping.

Comment: Any operation (cpu instruction) takes up "power" (clock cycles) in a computer - nothing is free. The question seem to be off-topic for SO though (too broad) as this is a wide topic and it would also depend on each browser's actual implementation and method of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will and as Epistemex has said the amount of power it takes is dependant upon browser and client.

Treat the canvas as if it has a mask applied equal to it's size.  You could drawImage a high resolution copy of the Mona Lisa and only see her face.  However that hires image will have to have been loaded into memory somewhere.

Looking at it from the other angle (which I think you were driving at).  Anything that doesn't get displayed on the canvas is technically "lost" so the canvas won't take up any extra memory once you've finished the current draw.  However the process of drawing items that aren't display does cost overhead.

Hope that helped a little - expand your question if you'd like more info

Comment: if that's the case, does the invisible canvas cost less drawing time as compared to a visible canvas?

Comment: I believe (and I could be wrong) that it will take exactly the same amount of processing time but zero time to draw to screen.  So there will be a time saving which will be dependant upon hardware - would be interesting to see some stats on this if somebody had time.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ohh, I'm just trying to get a clear idea behind why the hidden canvas method is suggested by many people.Cause most of the time they suggest to draw everything in the hidden canvas and draw the hidden canvas out again, just wanted to know for sure if the hidden canvas doesn't take the bitmap drawing time as they say bitmap drawing is very power consuming.

Comment: What you're describing is a technique called buffering.  The hidden canvas is useful if you're performing a lot of transitions and changes - so using lots of .save() doing something like rotating or similar and then .restore().  Because the canvas doesn't render to screen you're saving a bit of power for each draw to the canvas.  You could then do some transition to the whole canvas (rotate it 90 degrees for example and apply a colour tint) and then just draw it onto the visible canvas.